# Maximum distance between sink basket and floor outlet pipe

Tags: sink, vent, drainage

I am installing double bowl sink on the benchtop. I am not sure what maximum length is allowed between trap below the sink and pipe outlet on the floor?

Comment: there shouldn't be a pipe outlet on the floor.  sinks discharge through p-traps into vertical pipes to allow venting.